# ¿Cómo sabe C++ si una función existe y además dónde está ubicada?

Tags: c++, funciones

Pueden explicar este código si quieren:

```
int suma(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}

int main(){
    cout<<suma(5,1)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

No entiendo como C++ sabe que existe suma(int,int) y además donde está, si primero C++ ejecuta la función main()...

¡Gracias!

PD: Últimamente he estado muy perdido con las funciones... He investigado y sigo con dudas.

Comment: El compilador procesa el código de arriba a abajo, entonces cuando llega a main, la función 'suma' ya está declarada, así que puede llamarla. Luego, en tiempo de ejecución se ejecuta main, y main llama a suma.

Comment: Casi no entiendo...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Me llega la pregunta vos. Si quieres la respuesta corta, el resumen esta al final. Pero creo que conocer un poco el proceso para llegar a el ejecutable te ayudara a entender la respuesta. Siempre complementa lo poquito que te digo yo aquí con unas googleadas.

### ¿Como se pasa de C++ a un ejecutable?

Cuando tu compilas tu programa de C++, se pasa por los siguientes pasos:

1. Pasa el pre procesador
2. Se ensambla
3. Se compila
4. Y se linkea (Se pasa por el linker, no se como es el termino correcto en español)

Comento brevemente cada uno, siendo mas importantes los últimos 2.

#### 1. El preprocesador

Este es el que va ejecutando las instrucciones que empiezan con el `#` como el `#include<archivo>` que literalmente pega el archivo en el lugar. O los `#define` que va sustituyendo tus macros.

#### 2. El ensamblamiento

Como lo dice el nombre, aquí tu programa pasa de C++ a asembler. No solo eso, sino que como comentaba @braver, se procesa el código que arriba a abajo. Aquí es donde se verán los errores. Por ejemplo, si colocabas el código de este modo:

```cpp
int main(){
    cout<<suma(5,1)<<endl;
    return 0;
}

int suma(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

Te hubiera tirado un error de compilación. Va de arriba a abajo, y se topa con una funcion que no conocia, entonces tira el error. Lo que se hace es entonces decirle que existe la funcion pero sin definirla. Asi:

```cpp
int suma(int a, int b);

int main(){
    cout<<suma(5,1)<<endl;
    return 0;
}

int suma(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

Ahora sabe que existe, aunque cuando ve que la llamas en el main aun no sabe que es lo que hace.

Aquí el resultado será que tendremos las 2 funciones: `main` y `suma`

#### 3. Compilación

En este punto va a ser código de maquina, casi listo para correr.

#### 4. El linker

Este es el paso importante, y el que resuelve tu pregunta (pero no le podíamos entrar de un solo). El compilador ya conoce todas las funciones, ahora el linker va a "irlas colocando en donde tocan" (*No es exactamente así, pero esta forma de verlo nos funciona*).

Por eso un código como este:

```cpp
int suma(int a, int b);

int main(){
    cout<<suma(5,1)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Tira error hasta que llega al linker. El compilador cree que la función existe, y se espera que se tenga la implementación al llegar al linker. *Como no la conoce, el linker tira un error*.

### En resumen

> No entiendo como C++ sabe que existe suma(int,int) y además donde está, si primero C++ ejecuta la función main()...

Sabe que existe ya sea cuando la defines así: `int suma(int a, int b);` o cuando la implementas. Luego el linker se encarga de que el main pueda ejecutar la función suma.

## Extra

Veo este comentario:

> Pero, ¿Cómo C++ lee la declaración de la función si primero se ejecuta la función main()?

Y creo que mas o menos se porque la duda. El código pasa por todo un proceso antes de ser un ejecutable. No va directamente a la función main y la empieza a ejecutar, como si fuera un script. Si quieres profundizar un poco mas en como funciona, te recomiendo estos videos de *The Cherno*. Uno en [el linker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4s55GgAg0I), y el otro en el [compilador](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tIqpEmWMLI). Para no trabarnos en varios lugares, a veces es necesario bajar un poco el nivel de abstracción y conocer que es lo que se hace debajo del capote para resolver nuestras dudas. El lo explica bastante claro.

Comment: el término que buscas para _linker_ es enlazador

Comment: @eferion Muchas gracias

Comment: Ah, si no entendí mal, entonces, los programas en C++, no se ejecutan primero en la función main() sino que se ejecutan desde arriba hacia abajo, hasta que se topan con la función main()?

Comment: @Israel nótese que [en Meta se está debatiendo sobre tu edición y tu rechazo a otra sugerencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4858/83). Lo mismo quieres pasarte por allí para dar tu opinión :)

Comment: @ElblackNinja No, el compilador lee todo el codigo, pasa por el proceso que ves arriba, y el programa ya en ejecutable empieza a correr por la funcion main

Comment: Mm ya entiendo, gracias :]!!

Answer (score 4):

C++ sabe que una que una función existe al leer una declaración: una declaración de función C++ sigue esta sintaxis:

```
tipo_de_retorno nombre(parámetros);
```

Eso crea una función llamada `nombre` cuyo tipo de retorno es de tipo `tipo_de_retorno` y sus parámetros son `parámetros`, por ejemplo:

```
void hola(); // Función 'hola' que no devuelve nada.
int mundo(int x); // Función 'mundo' que devuelve un entero y recibe un entero.
```

Recuerda que la declaración de una función es sólo una parte del trabajo, después de declararla deberás definirla (darle cuerpo):

```
void hola(); // Declaración.

void hola() // Definición
{
    // Cuerpo de la función.
}
```

Si defines una función sin declararla, la definición contará también como declaración.

Las funciones definidas se compilan y acaban escritas en una [unidad de traducción](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (UdT), lo que se escribe en la UdT no es la función tal y como aparece en el código si no que recibe un nombre personalizado por el compilador ([*mangled name*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)).

Cuando todas las funciones han sido compiladas, el [enlazador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) enlaza todas las llamadas a la función con el código que les corresponde.

---

En resumen:

- Sabe que una función existe porque ha sido declarada.
- Sabe dónde está porque la ha compilado en un objeto intermedio.
- Sabe ejecutarla porque ha enlazado en el objeto ejecutable.

Answer (score 3):

Para explicarlo de una forma más sencilla es necesario entender cómo funciona C++ de la forma más básica. C++ es un lenguaje compilado, lo cual significa que es un lenguaje que hace uso de un programa (Compilador) el cual se encarga de traducir el código fuente a código binario.

El código que has formulado en la pregunta, está escrito en código fuente, el cual, el ordenador no puede comprender debido a que el ordenador habla en código maquina (unos y ceros).

Para que el ordenador pueda entender lo que se ha escrito, C++ hace uso del compilador, el cual se encarga de analizar todo el código fuente de C++. Este proceso de análisis se encarga de leer todas las funciones y variables del código fuente.

Para el compilador de C++, la lectura funciona de arriba a abajo, por lo que, para este caso, lo primero en leer es la función "suma". Después de leer la función "suma", el compilador pasa a leer la función "main", la cual, contiene en su interior la función "suma", pero esto no supone ningún problema, debido a que el Compilador ya ha leído dicha función.

Una vez leídas todas las funciones y variables, el Compilador asigna "main" como la principal función en ser ejecutada, y posteriormente devuelve un fichero en código binario, el cual contiene las instrucciones que equivalen a tu código fuente.

Este proceso asegura que cuando ejecutes dicho archivo binario, no se produzca ningún problema, debido a que, "main" ya conoce la definición de la función "suma", puesto que el Compilador se ha encargado de proporcionarle dicha definición.