# solo funciona la primera función, el resto no se muestra en consola. C++

Tags: c++

Como puedo hacer para que se ejecute mas de una funcion, por ejemplo:

```
void main (){}
void main1 (){}
void main2 (){}
void main3 (){}
```

y que las 4 las muestre la consola.
Lo que no entiendo es porque se ejectuda solo la primera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que, tienes que llamar a esas funciones; el compilador asigna a `main` la función en ser ejecutada una vez inicia el programa. main es como el "jefe" del programa.

---

> Como puedo hacer para que se ejecute mas de una funcion

#### NO es posible

ya que C++ no posee múltiples [**Call Stacks**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pila_de_llamadas).

---

Para llamar a una función, solo tienes que poner el nombre el nombre de la función y los parámetros.

Ahora veamos... Quieres llamar a esas 3 funciones, ¿cierto? Pues, primero tienes especificar que hacen exactamente esas 3 funciones. ¿Por qué? Porque, el compilador o enlazador tienen que saber que hacen esas funciones y también, tienen que saber que existen, para cuando se invoquen esas funciones, no haya un error de compilador o enlazador.

Ya, vamos a ver como tiene que estar el código:

```
void main1(){
//Código de la función
  ...
}
```

```
void main2(){
//Código de la función
 ...
}
```

```
void main3(){
//Código de la función
 ...
}
```

```
int main(){

main1();
main2();
main3();

  return 0;
}
```

---

Ahora expliquemos algunas cosas:

- ¿Por qué se cambió el void a int a la función main?

La razón es simple: la función main debe retornar 0 para indicar que el programa finalizó con éxito. A veces no es necesario, pero es la forma correcta de implementar la función main (no exactamente, porque le faltan los parámetros: `argc` y `argv`).

- ¿Por qué las 3 funciones se pusieron arriba de la función main?

Esto es porque el compilador o enlazador debe conocer que hacen esas funciones, y además para indicarles que existen (esto también, se puede hacer con [**Prototipos de función**](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/c-language/function-prototypes?view=msvc-160)).

Para más información, puedes consultar esta pregunta:[***¿Cómo sabe C++ si una función existe y además dónde está ubicada?***](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394771/c%C3%B3mo-sabe-c-si-una-funci%C3%B3n-existe-y-adem%C3%A1s-d%C3%B3nde-est%C3%A1-ubicada)

También, puedes completar mi respuesta, con la respuesta de @Pablochaches:

> > Lo que sucede es que los programas tienen un **punto de entrada**. Este es el lugar en el que todos los programas inician. Tu código pasa por todo un proceso antes de ser un ejecutable. Hablo de el proceso en la respuesta a esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394771/c%c3%b3mo-sabe-c-si-una-funci%c3%b3n-existe-y-adem%c3%a1s-d%c3%b3nde-est%c3%a1-ubicada/394778#394778).

> > En el paso final, en el linker, se dice por que funcion empieza el programa. Si tienes un `main1` o un `main2` ya no importa en este punto. El linker, por convención, dice que el programa empieza por la función main. Si quieres que se ejecuten las otras, tendras que llamarlas dentro del main como dijo @eferion

*Nota: Si estoy equivocado en algo que mencioné, son libres de corregirme (***esta nota NO está en la respuesta de @Pablochaches***).*

Answer (score 4):

simplemente invócalas en el orden que desees desde el main o desde cualquier otra función:

```
int main()
{
  main1();
  main2();
  main3();
  main4();
}
```

Eso sí ,date cuenta que las funciones se ejecutarán de forma secuencial, es decir hasta que no termine de ejecutarse `main1` no se ejecutará `main2`.

Aunque te sugeriría usar nombres más descriptivos para las funciones

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabia eso

Answer (score 2):

No he trabajado nunca con C++, pero sí con Java y por lo que veo, eso es similar al main de Java, sólo se ejecuta el primero (el primero que sea main, no main1, o main 20). Por lo que, no puedes ejecutar varios mains. Si quieres ejecutar los nuevos mains, mételos dentro del main principal como llamadas a funciones.

Comment: Gracias,  seguro es eso

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que los programas tienen un **punto de entrada**. Este es el
lugar en el que todos los programas inician. Tu código pasa por todo un proceso
antes de ser un ejecutable. Hablo de el proceso en la respuesta a esta
[pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394771/c%c3%b3mo-sabe-c-si-una-funci%c3%b3n-existe-y-adem%c3%a1s-d%c3%b3nde-est%c3%a1-ubicada/394778#394778).

En el paso final, en el linker, se dice por que funcion empieza el programa. Si tienes un `main1` o un `main2` ya no importa en este punto. El linker, por convención, dice que el programa empieza por la función main. Si quieres que se ejecuten las otras, tendras que llamarlas dentro del main como dijo @eferion